# Ansible module java_cert to convert JKS to PKCS12

Tags: java, ansible

The java_cert ansible module does not have the feature to convert/export a Java Key Store (.jks) file to PKCS12 (.p12)

Essentially I want to perform the following command using Ansible java_cert module

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore <server_truststore>.jks -destkeystore .p12 -deststoretype PKCS12
```

Appreciate your suggestions.

Thank you in Advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on this https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/java_cert_module.html `java_cert` is not able to do what you want. The output of `java_cert` module is jks not p12.

You may create an issue here https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues

For now you may use

```
- name: export jks to p12
  command: keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore <server_truststore>.jks -destkeystore.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12
```